# Rake, bundle, rails command not found on rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, centos, bundler

I just installed rvm + rails 3+ on centos 6.0 at Rackspace cloud server. Everything works fine, but sometimes when i ssh to server i can't use rake, bundle or any other rails related commands it always shows me errors like:

```
bash: rake: command not found
```

when i try to run bundle install it shows me this error:

```
ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.
```

but i do have it installed for sure and it worked before.I can use `rvm rake db:migrate` - but it used to without rvm prefix...Please help i dont know why is that happening - maybe something wrong with bash profile...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you used a ruby ?

```
 rvm use 1.9.3
```

this will select properly environment and make all commands working properly.

to make this setting permanent for new sessions also use:

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

Comment: Hey mpapis it works once i type this command, but once i ssh to server again - its broken again and i hate to type this command again.